# Combine columns from one table in one column in power query

Tags: power-query

I have a table (example). X - Some value.

Num A1 A2 A3  B1 B2 B3  C1 C2 C3

1      x  x  x   x  x  x   x  x  x

2      x  x  x   x  x  x   x  x  x

3      x  x  x   x  x  x   x  x  x

I need to make a table like this. I hope you understood what I need.

Num    Value1   Value2   Value3

1          A1                   B1              C1

1         A2                   B2               C2

1         A3                    B3              C3

2         A1 ...

2         A2 ...

2        A3 ...

3         A1 ...

Answer (score 0):

The key steps needed are:

1. Select Num column and choose **Unpivot Other Columns**
2. Add steps to split the resulting Attribute column (formerly the column headings) into 2 columns
3. Pivot on the column for the first character of Attribute, choosing Value as the Values Column and Don't Aggregate as the Aggregate Value Function.

Here's a test query (including sample data) so you can walk through the steps:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("Hc6xCcAwDETRVYTrELA0ge/6LGAyQsrsH/00Bw/7G+89rveJNWNlrArNUIYqPMMZrnEfe/TpPLnCVI+goKChoZt/kiRJwrs9goKChoad5J8USZEUCZ9hoKChYSf9sfsD", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4", "Column1.5", "Column1.6", "Column1.7", "Column1.8", "Column1.9", "Column1.10"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}, {"Column1.4", type text}, {"Column1.5", type text}, {"Column1.6", type text}, {"Column1.7", type text}, {"Column1.8", type text}, {"Column1.9", type text}, {"Column1.10", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Num", Int64.Type}, {"A1", type text}, {"A2", type text}, {"A3", type text}, {"B1", type text}, {"B2", type text}, {"B3", type text}, {"C1", type text}, {"C2", type text}, {"C3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type2", {"Num"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Inserted Text Range" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Text Range", each Text.Middle([Attribute], 1, 1), type text),
    #"Inserted First Characters" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Range", "First Characters", each Text.Start([Attribute], 1), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted First Characters",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[#"First Characters"]), "First Characters", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Text Range"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"A", "Value1"}, {"B", "Value2"}, {"C", "Value3"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```